# Как обратиться к базе данных MS SQL на локальной машине из контейнера Docker?

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

Всем привет!
Не могу подключиться к базе данных из контейнера. MS SQL Server установлен и запущен на моей локальной машине (с которого я запускаю контейнеры Docker).
Запускаю в контейнере скрипт на python, в котором идёт коннект с моей базой данных. Но на этапе подключения уходит в ошибку таймаут и пишет, что ms sql cannot connect to local server.
Включил TCP/IP, но не помогло.
Мне кажется, я не знаю как правильно открыть доступ/порты к базе данных локальной машины.

p.s.
Мне не нужно запускать MS SQL Server отдельно в другом контейнере и связывать их, сервер базы данных находится на моем ПК, с которого я запускаю все контейнеры Docker.

Answer (score 2):

Для подключения к сервисам запущеным на хосте, стоит использовать специальное DNS имя `host.docker.internal`

[Источник](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)

Альтернативным решением можно использовать ключ `docker run --network=host` тогда `localhost` для контейнера и хоста будет единый

**UPD**
Так же проверьте в настройках firewall что открыты подключения к порту 1433

Comment: И ещё firewall нужно или отключить или настроить - открыть 1433

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо, добавил в ответ

Comment: В этом случае это не важно, но замечу, что `host.docker.internal`, к сожалению, непереносимый способ. Он не работает на линуксе, а только на windows и macos.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, где я должен указать "host.docker.internal"? В строке подключения к базе данных или при запуске докер контейнера?

Comment: @Виктор host.docker.internal - для мак и виндовс систем - это днс запись, показывающая адрес вашего хоста, на котором запущен докер. Использовать его надо, для вашего примера, в строке подключения к базе. Однако имейте ввиду, что для Линукс систем этот метод не работает. В Linux системах надо указать ключ `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` при запуске докера (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/61424570#61424570)